# Compose 1.1.1 kotlin compiler issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've got an issue on my project.

It's a new and clean compose project and I'm using

**Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3**
**Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8309675, built on March 16, 2022**

***Update infos : I have the latest version of kotlin (1.6.20) installed (according to android studio) and but i have many versions in my kotlin cache folder, is it normal ?***

The only things I've done is follow the android studio advices to set the compose version to 1.1.1

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.1.1'
    }
}
```

and added an other dependency for androidx.compose.material3

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.animation:animation:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
//    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"

    //Material 3 compose
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha09"

    def room_version = "2.4.2"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-common:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

}
```

and I'm having this error :

```
Task :app:compileDebugKotlin
e: This version (1.1.1) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.6.10 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.5.21 which is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!).
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    C:/Users/Ulkan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.5.30/5fd47535cc85f9e24996f939c2de6583991481b0/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30.jar (version 1.5)
    C:/Users/Ulkan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.5.30/525f5a7fa6d7790a571c07dd24214ed2dda352fe/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.30.jar (version 1.5)
    C:/Users/Ulkan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.6.10/b8af3fe6f1ca88526914929add63cf5e7c5049af/kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
    C:/Users/Ulkan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.6.10/c118700e3a33c8a0d9adc920e9dec0831171925/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath
Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    C:/Users/Ulkan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.5.30/5fd47535cc85f9e24996f939c2de6583991481b0/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30.jar (version 1.5)
    C:/Users/Ulkan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.5.30/525f5a7fa6d7790a571c07dd24214ed2dda352fe/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.30.jar (version 1.5)
    C:/Users/Ulkan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.6.10/b8af3fe6f1ca88526914929add63cf5e7c5049af/kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
    C:/Users/Ulkan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.6.10/c118700e3a33c8a0d9adc920e9dec0831171925/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)


> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
```

Comment: Check out [Why should I not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3585796) and replace images with [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) code.

Comment: Your error clearly says what to do, if you just run search with **1.5.21** you'll find the place to replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade Kotlin version from `1.5.21` to `1.6.10` as the error message suggests

Comment: I think i already have the latest version :
211-1.6.20-release-275-AS7442.40

At least that is what android studio is saying me.

Comment: A friend explained to me that the version of the Kotlin IDE is not the version use by my project, so thank for the answer 

I was just looking at the wrong spot for the change. 

In case someone as the same issue, it's in build.gradle (not the .app one)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the mentioned below link which help to identify the version you are using for compose is compatible with which version of kotlin.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin

More to add,

1. If you are using kotlin synthetic import, you have to replace all of them by using viewbinding or simple by calling findViewById.
2. **kotlin-android-extensions** is deprecated so replace it from **kotlin-parcelize**
3. If there is @Parcelize annotation used for model classes so you have to replace its import from  **kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize** to import **kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize**